# Registering and updating COM objects, same GUID or not?

Tags: c#, com, guid

I am generating COM objects with CodeDom which I release/register frequently on client machines (from C# for use in VBA).

Since I am generating these objects, I found it easier to get a new random GUID for each of them everytime I update/release the COM objects, rather than keeping track of fixed GUIDs.

Is that a potential source of issues ?

Comment: The Guid used to signify changes of binary compatibility - ie. on each compile, as long as your dll had the exactly same API, it would get the same Guid. Changing the Guid each time shouldn't have any adverse effects, other than potentially requiring more re-compilation of applications that link to the dlls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the [Guid] of an interface or class change when its public members change is a very hard requirement in COM.  Not doing so invokes a very nasty kind of DLL Hell, the client will call the wrong method or a method that doesn't exist.  Extremely hard to diagnose.  Changing the [Guid] ensures that the client code gets an error before it calls into nowhere.

In this particular scenario, the better approach is to **not** use the [Guid] attribute but leave it up to the CLR to auto-generate one.  It has a very good algorithm that keeps the guid stable as long as the interface or class members don't change.

Do note that having the guid change also requires the client code to be recompiled, if it uses early binding.  Since you didn't mention that as a step that was consistently done, there's some likelihood that the client code uses late binding.  Pretty easy to do in VBA, albeit that you lose some comforts like code completion and compile errors instead of runtime errors.  If it uses late binding then the [Guid] doesn't matter.  Check that code, if you see `Dim` without `As` or never added the type library then it is using late binding.

Comment: Thanks, that brings up some interesting concepts together which I'm not very familiar with. I am using Excel DNA to wrap up all DLLs as an XLL. I guess we call this early binding then ?

Comment: I haven't tinkered with XLLs much but I'm fairly sure it doesn't use COM at all.  It is a C based api.  Very unclear to me how that interops with your .NET server.

Comment: I am using what has been named a "COM server addin" from Excel DNA samples. The tool and the samples containing this one are available here : http://exceldna.codeplex.com/releases/view/66405

Answer (score 1):

You *must* change the guid of every **changed** com-api-signature.

@paul is right that changing guid will break binary compatibility. 
You must recompile every client that statically links to your com (i.e. a c# client).

You cann minimize client recompilation if you never change an existing com-api-signature but create a new additional method-signature.

This way old programms still can use the old api while new programms can benefit from the new api.